# unused deleted column causing error #1054 'order clause'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I had a column that I called 'lightbox' which I now have no need for however when i try and look at my table i get this error:
[image]

any help appreciated

Comment: Probably you filtered for lightbox once and now deleted it. Or you have an open SQL Tab where you still use "lightbox".

Comment: thanks for the reply. how do i check for that?

Comment: Simply logout from your pma and login again.